# Concatenate two values from a JSON object into a map[string]bool in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I am trying to concatenate two values, door and access, from a JSON object into a map[string]bool, which is declared inside a struct. Right now, I am getting the error:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Data.pasted of type
>   map[string]bool

The struct is defined as follows:

```
type AccessControl struct{
    SessionId string `json:"sessionId"`
    DoorAccess map[string]bool 
}
```

The JSON object I am getting from the server is:

```
{
    "sessionId": "232",
    "door": "Main Door",
    "access": true
}
```

And this is my function:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var data AccessControl
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do something that is not standard. In that case you should probably create your own Umarshaller.

http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/ 
https://medium.com/@nate510/dynamic-json-umarshalling-in-go-88095561d6a0

Answer (score 2):

your json and your struct are not representing the same object
your struct should be as follows:

```
    type AccessControl struct {
    SessionID string `json:"sessionId"`
    Door      string `json:"door"`
    Access    bool   `json:"access"`
    }
```

and for the "full example" that you asked for:

```
type ServerAccessControl struct {
    SessionID string `json:"sessionId"`
    Door      string `json:"door"`
    Access    bool   `json:"access"`
}

type AccessControl struct {
    SessionId  string `json:"sessionId"`
    DoorAccess map[string]bool
}

func main() {
    jsn := `{ "sessionId": "232", "door": "Main Door", "access": true }`
    var data ServerAccessControl
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsn), &data)
    accessControl := ServerAccessControlToAccessControl(&data)
    fmt.Println(accessControl)

}

//ServerAccessControlToAccessControl convert a access control obj from the server into a map based struct.
func ServerAccessControlToAccessControl(fromServer *ServerAccessControl) AccessControl {
    var accessControl AccessControl
    accessControl.SessionId = fromServer.SessionID
    accessControl.DoorAccess = make(map[string]bool)
    accessControl.DoorAccess[fromServer.Door] = fromServer.Access
    return accessControl
}
```

I created the ServerAccessControl struct which represent the json that you are getting from the server and the Access Control class as you wanted it.

It is important that you will notice that you are not getting a collection from the server, and if you plan to add more doors into your map, you will need to implement the logic your self.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, as I want to use a map, which has many doors.

Comment: You'll want to have two structs most likely then. One that represents the return from the server, and one that you want to pass around your program. Have a function that will convert between the two to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a custom Unmarshaller. Here's an example. See my comments for articles explaining the process.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var data = `{
    "sessionId": "232",
    "door": "Main Door",
    "access": true
}`

type AccessControl struct {
    SessionId  string `json:"sessionId"`
    DoorAccess map[string]bool
}

func (a *AccessControl) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {

    tmp := struct {
        SessionID string `json:"sessionId"`
        Door      string `json:"door"`
        Access    bool   `json:"access"`
    }{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    a.SessionId = tmp.SessionID
    a.DoorAccess = map[string]bool{tmp.Door: tmp.Access}
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var ac AccessControl
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &ac)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ac)
}
```